# How can I get Active Directory username from their Exchange email address?

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server

This is the code I am trying to use but I am not really getting anywhere with it:

```
public static string GetUserIdFromEmail(string emailAddress)
    {
        string displayName = string.Empty;

        if (emailAddress.Contains("@sub.domain.edu") || emailAddress.Contains("@domain.edu"))
        {
            displayName = emailAddress.Split(new char[] { '@' })[0];
        }
        else
        {
            //no active directory account.
            return string.Empty;
        }


        // set up domain context
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            // find user by display name
            try
            {
                UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, displayName);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    return user.SamAccountName; // or UserPrincipleName
                }
                else
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "Error";
            }
        }
    }
```

These are the things I know regarding our current systems:

1. Emails are going to be unique and follow a certain naming convention
2. The naming convention is first letter of first name and whole last name (dstanley).
3. Some older accounts on Exchange are first.last@email.com
4. I have no idea what i am doing, but I know what I want.

I want to be able to take a users domain email address and find their record in active directory. Is the code above on the right track or is there something simpler that I can do?

Comment: Personally, I like the guts admitting number 4.

Comment: ha, guts? More like a 'please don't throw rocks at me if this is a stupid question' kind of statement. I have just never really worked with intranet applications, and trying to programatically get AD stuff.

Comment: Far too often in our profession due people fail to realize it's completely okay to admit you have no clue what you're doing. That's one of the reason this site exists.

Answer (score 0):

In order to gain access to a users email using the standard active directory library you must first have the samaccount.  This means that the solution to this problem requires you to iterate through every samaccount and compare the email address until you find a match.

PsuedoCode

```
foreach(user in activedirectory) 
{
  if (user.email = targeted_email)
  {
      return matched samaccount
  }
}
```

I do not believe there is a better way to approach this and therefore it is a resource intensive solution.